# is .htaccess size reduce performance of site ? what is max size of .htacess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have used .htaccess  in my project. 
I have use rewrite rule for several pages.
Can anyone tell me what is max size of .htaccess? As I read if size of .htaccess increase web site performance down (i.e. it slows down).

Answer (score 2):

2gigs is the max and seems to me I start to see a load issue after about 57,000 lines of code an example is I added 360,000 lines of code country blocks and my connectiobn to the server added at least a 10 to 15-second delay on page loads that is a big difference from a 2 second login and page load.

Comment: Also, take a look at this https://briansnelson.com/How_to_block_or_allow_countries_using_GeoIP_and_.htaccess with this approach we can go from say 360,000 lines of deny from in the .htaccess to10 lines of code for the same 360,000 lines of deny from.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess is used by the webserver to control different things when the page is requested. Since I believe the file is parsed for every page request, you should probably keep its contents to a minimum. However, I'm not aware of any size limit.